# Difference between using Application.StartupUri and handling Startup event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've developed a WPF application which uses an advanced 3rd party UserControl; the UserControl shows an interactive map. If I open the main window of the application by specifying `StartupUri="MainWindow"` in XAML, or if I start the application from code using `app.Run(new MainWindow())`, then everything works fine. However, if I instead handle the Application Startup event this way

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    new MainWindow().Show();
}
```

then I get the following exception when I start interacting with the map:

> Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.

Why might this happen - is there some difference in which thread does what between these different ways of starting the application? Here is a partial stack trace for the exception:

> ```
> at System.Windows.Freezable.EnsureConsistentDispatchers(DependencyObject owner, DependencyObject child)
> at System.Windows.Freezable.OnFreezablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject oldValue, DependencyObject newValue, DependencyProperty property)
> at System.Windows.Media.RenderData.PropagateChangedHandler(EventHandler handler, Boolean adding)
> at System.Windows.Media.DrawingVisual.RenderClose(IDrawingContent newContent)
> at System.Windows.Media.RenderDataDrawingContext.DisposeCore()
> at System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
> at some3rdPartyClass.BuildVisual(Brush fg, Brush bg)
> ```

Comment: @Machine Learning Is your question why I would want to handle the Startup event instead? If so: The question as posed shows a simplified example; in reality I want to call a constructor of MainWindow with different arguments.

Comment: How can I reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how you can reproduce it without that same 3rd party UserControl (which I am not at liberty to share).

Comment: Why can't you just instantiate and use those in the main window's constructor? Also is it possible that the 3rd party invoke a thread and that happens to be the UI one when the xaml is in the starturi

Comment: Try making the `Build Action` of application to `Page` and write your own `Main` with `STAThread` attrib.  Something like [this](https://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2010/04/20/writing-a-custom-main-method-for-wpf-applications/)

Comment: @MKloster As I'm unable to check that.  I can't make this as an answer.  Let me know if it works so that I can make this as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gopichandar That worked, but that was basically the same as the "app.Run(new MainWindow)" approach mentioned in my initial post, although I had implemented that by modifying a Windows Forms application; this way of doing it is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 3rd party (but obviously I can't test it) invoke a thread and that happens to be the UI one when the xaml is in the starturi ....

Try this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action(() => {
        //pls share what kind of arguments you're using...
        new MainWindow().Show();
    })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! It doesn't quite answer my original question though - why is there such a difference between the two approaches?

Comment: Pls mark as answered :-) that explains that the thread was not the UI when it did not start from the starturi

Comment: The application is actually a host that support various addins, and the argument is a list of the addins to be used (and there are several different launchers (executables) that use different lists). While testing this bug, though, I have used the basic constructor with no arguments.